# How to attach a non Google Drive file to an email via an automated Gmail Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google script that sends e-mails via gmail to recipients.

The code looks like:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = row[2];
    var name = row[3];
    var message = "Dear " + row[3] + ",\n\n" + row[1]; // Assemble the body text
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

I can see that there is a way to attach a file that is located in Google Drive. via:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 });
```

But is there a way to attach a file which is not stored in Google Drive (for example a file stored on my C:\ drive)?

Comment: How will you access local drive from Google servers?

Comment: Sorry newbie to Google Script, is attaching an file from a non Google Drive location a big deal? In answer to your question I don't know

Comment: non-Google-drive isn't a big deal. But local vs cloud is.  Script runs on Google servers in the cloud, which doesn't have access to your local files. Your file needs to be in the cloud or the script(say, python) must run locally(accessing Gmail API).

Comment: @Stacey Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, as other workaround, how about this? When the files are uploaded from local PC to Google Drive, Google Apps Script is run as the trigger, and send the email with the attachment files. In this workaround, Web Apps is used and your script can be used. So when you send email on Google side, you can use your script. You can select from several workarounds.